# What is the best way to show a popup when the user looks my website for the first time?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am developing a website using Code Igniter. I want to show a popup when a user visits my websites for the first time. If he is refreshing again it shoudn't be coming again. Now i am checking for session variable and if it doesn't exist, I am showing that popup. After that I am forcing that user to click a button to close popup. And then i am sending an request to server to set that session variable. So that if that user refresh page, that popup will not come again.

**Is there any best way to complete this action?**

Comment: What is best for you?

Comment: use persistant data client side with some logic as localstorage or, for older browsers support, use cookies

Comment: How long is your session timeout? A cookie with a long expiration might be better than a session flag.

Comment: Use cookies, not local storage, in case you end up having https as well as http (cookies traverse both, whereas local storage does not :))

Comment: Surely you only want the popup to disappear when the user clicks the close button, not when they refresh. Also CodeIgniter is one word...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cookies on my own (codeigniter) website.

I used the [jquery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) plugin. and [JQUERY COOKIE](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

I did something like this:

```
$(function() {

    if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') {

    $("#dialog").dialog({ 
            width: 450, 
            modal: "true",
            hide: "fade",
            show: "fade",
            closeOnEscape: false, 
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Welcome to my site', 
            close: function(event, ui){ 
                location.reload(true); 
            },
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();  }
        }).dialog("open");
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({background: "#000", opacity: 0.8});

    $.cookie('showDialog', 'false', { expires: 365 }); // set the cookie, with expiry after 1 day

}
```

And my dialog code:

```
<div id="dialog" class="hidden" title="Welcome to my website">

// Content for dialog
// Content for dialog

</div>
```

Now when you click on the button 'close' or whatever your button says. the cookie will be set and the dialog will not be shown if the cookie is set. I added an expiration of 1 year. So if people don't delete their cookies, the dialog will not be shown this year.

Answer (score 2):

I don`t think what you are describing is a good idea. 
From UX point of view - having a popup on page opening is not cool experience at all.

Answer (score 1):

Very few sites uses this approach, and often for a reason. What is a pop up? It's often the result of an action made by the user, or at leasts that's the idea. If you press that button and a pop up appears, that's fine. But if you visit this new site for the first time and you get a pop up in your face before even deciding that the site does, that doesn't come out well for you.

If you insist on doing it like this, I would rather suggest running it through [javascript cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). It doesn't demand extra perfomance on your server for *every* unique user and doesn't contain sensitive data. In worst case they manipulate the cookie and get the pop up again.

Personally, I'd prefer to do this like Youtube does; I enter the site and gets a clearly marked box containing information which I can actively choose to click on for more information:

[image]
(This account is handled by castlin.se. Read More)

This approach is efficient for informing the users, giving the ability to gain more info whilst not being in their way for what the user often wanted to do instead.

---

> Is there any best way to complete this action?

No. There are several ways with their reasons and advantages. We can present you solutions, but we can't say "this is the one you *must* use". Which the exception of potentiel sql injections; they are a "must" handle :)